# rails active_storage:install IS NOT WORKING

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api, rails-activestorage

I have updated my rails api application from 5.1 to 5.2. 
I am using rails api only.
I am trying to use the active storage. I think the problem is due to the line `config.api_only = true` in `config/application.rb`.

I did lot of google but did not find any thing how to use active storage in rails api.

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.5.1'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'rack-cors'

# Auth
gem 'bcrypt'
gem 'jwt'

#Media file upload
gem 'activestorage'

# gem 'devise', '4.4.3'
# gem 'devise-jwt', '~> 0.5.6'
gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0', require: true

# backgroud jobs
gem 'sidekiq'

# fast boot
gem 'bootsnap', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7'
  gem 'brakeman'
  gem 'rubocop'
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'foreman'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'annotate'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Here is my `config/application.rb`

```
require_relative 'boot'

require "rails"
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_model/railtie"
require "active_job/railtie"
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "action_view/railtie"
require "action_cable/engine"
require "active_storage"
# require "sprockets/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module CelebrationBackend
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Only loads a smaller set of middleware suitable for API only apps.
    # Middleware like session, flash, cookies can be added back manually.
    # Skip views, helpers and assets when generating a new resource.
    config.api_only = true

    config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
  end
end
```

While running the `rails activestorage:install` in to console.
I am getting the following error:

rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'activestorage:install' (see --tasks)
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in`perform'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in`'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in`block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in`require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in`block in require'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in`require'
/home/sourabh/dev/celebration/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`load'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in`call'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in`'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/home/sourabh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@celeb/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`'
/home/sourabh/dev/celebration/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/home/sourabh/dev/celebration/bin/spring:15:in`'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in`'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

I am not getting the exact thing what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
require "active_storage"
```

You need to require the engine:

```
require "active_storage/engine"
```

Comment: After I did this, I get a new error now - `rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_storage/engine
`. Another user reported the same issue here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50915148/cant-get-past-error-in-rails-setup-loaderror-cannot-load-such-file-active and looks like he solved it by moving to the older version of rails

Answer (score 7):

The current rails official documents talks about the new application. But
**if you're upgrading a pre 5.2 app**, you have to **add** or **uncomment** the field in `application.rb`

```
require "active_storage/engine"
```

For the new application, this will be already added.

Answer (score 1):

Try running command in the project root

`bin/rails active_storage:install`

or

`rake active_storage:install`

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: I have the same issue as well

Comment: Worked with bin/rails active_storage:install (with _ )

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to `application.rb`:

```
require 'active_storage/engine'
```