# Can't get past error in Rails Setup- `LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_storage/engine`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to setup a new Rails application and having an issue that I can't seem to resolve. When trying to run `rake db:drop` or `rake db:create` I keep getting the error:

`LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_storage/engine`

At first I was getting an error:

`LoadError: cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup` but was able to clear that after adding it to my gemfile.

I see some info on Github that suggests uncommenting `require "active_storage/engine"` but I've already done that. Not sure what to do.

Comment: do you have the activestorage gem installed?

Comment: @BM5k I saw on their github that activestorage was merged into Rails and I didn't see a gem. That's why I'm a little confused by it. I'm new to Rails so not sure of the ins and outs.

Comment: Rails itself is a meta-gem that includes several gems (actioncable, actionmailer, actionpack, actionview, activejob, activemodel, activerecord, activestorage, & activesupport). 

Since rails uses bundler to manage dependencies you should be able to run `bundle show` to show the list of gems that were installed. You may need to run `bundle install` if any dependencies are missing.

Comment: @BM5k OK, thank you. I ran bundle install but kept getting the error. I just reverted back to an older version of Rails as a work around.

Comment: Is downgrading Rails version the only fix for this issue?

Comment: Have you run the task `rails active_storage:install` And then migrate?

Answer (score 3):

I got this error whilst downgrading my app from rails 6.0 to 5.2

Check in your `config/application.rb` for the line

```rb
require "action_mailbox/engine"
```

and try commenting it out.

Comment: The question is asking about a new rails app - not a downgrade

Comment: I was downgrading from 6.0 to 5.2 and this helped.

Comment: i cant find this. what should i do

Comment: Try running `grep -rin "/engine" *` from your rails root dir (-r is for recursive, -i is for case-sensitive, -n shows the line number in the found file). Maybe you can find that way, a line (e.g. `require ".../engine"`) that can not be loaded and produces the error?