# rails active_storage:install gives error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rails-activestorage

Note- there are some other questions that seem to ask the same thing, but the solutions there dont work for me. So this is a bit different.

I'm trying to go through a tutorial on active storage

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html

I'm on MacOS

I do `rails new blahapp` `cd blahapp`  so a fresh rails application.

I get the error

`Don't know how to build task 'active_storage:install'`

Is saw these questions [rails active_storage:install IS NOT WORKING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781131/rails-active-storageinstall-is-not-working)  and https://github.com/rails/activestorage/tree/archive#installation

I tried what's there and it's still not working, i'll elaborate..

I then tried  adding `gem "activestorage"` to Gemfile, and did bundle install

Same error

I then tried opening the file `config/application.rb` and adding the line `require "active_storage"`   Then the error changed a little bit

It said  `"Don't know how to build task 'active_storage:install'.......... did you mean? activestorage:install`

So, even though the guide says `rails active_storage:install`  I tried `rails activestorage:install`  and it said

```
"Made storage and tmp/storage directories for development and testing.  
Copied default configuration to config/storage_serivces.ymp
rails aborted.
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/apple/blahapp/db/migrate/.............active_storage_create_tables.rb
```

Comment: What version of ruby / rails are you using?

Comment: @rosalynn rails 5.1.6,    Ruby 2.5.0p0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since active storage was introduced in Rails 5.2, you need to be using that version for it to work. Try running "gem install rails" or (see full update instructions [here](http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html)) then creating a new app and following the instructions as usual.

Comment: thanks, I just tried editing Gemfile and changing the rails version to 5.2.0 , did bundle update, then the rails active_storage:install gave no error.