# Active storage installation does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I have a Rails application for which I wanna install the gem *active storage* so that I can save photos on my application and interact with them. Despite that, I input in the console
 `rails active_storage: install`
and I get the following error:

```
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_storage
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/config/application.rb:4:in `require'
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/config/application.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
C:/Users/andri/Desktop/hoagieShop/hoagieShop/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Does anyone understand why? I tried the solution provided here: [rails active_storage:install IS NOT WORKING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50781131/rails-active-storageinstall-is-not-working) but it did not work.

Comment: (1) have you added the gem to your .Gemfile, (2) have you run `bundle install` on that file?

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I forgot to run bundle install. But now I did it an this gives me an error as well. Where should I post it so that you can see it?

Comment: delete the gemlock file and run bundle , then try again

Comment: @ffblord what's the new error?

Comment: @ffblord just post it above, so other people can also see the problem. EDIT your post and add an UPDATE section

Answer (score 0):

in terminal/app folder

reset db

```
  rake db:reset
```

migrate db

```
  rake db:migrate
```

update the gem file

```
  bundle install
```